# HTML5Shiv for IE9 download tag

Tags: html, html5shiv

Does HTML5Shiv enable me to use the download tag as per below:

```
     <a download="expenses.xlsx" href="betalingsgrad.xlsx">Download her</a>
```

I have tried making it work, but with no succes. As far as i can tell, it only allows me to use the styles that HTML5 provides, is this correct?

Is there any other Polyfills that would then allow me to use the above?

Another option is that im simply using HTML5Shiv incorrectly.

Comment: I don't think that HTML5shiv has support for this. Even support in modern browsers is not really good, [see](http://caniuse.com/download).

Answer (score 0):

It seems that HTML5Shiv is not including `download` *attribute* for `a` tag.

There is no word "download" in `html5shiv.js`.

You can check browser support for "download" as well as for other features using excellent caniuse.com:
http://caniuse.com/#feat=download

Currently only recent versions of Firefox, Chrome, Opera and Blackberry browser are supporting "download" attribute.

Comment: Well that's not the answer i like, but it's the correct one nonetheless, thank you.